# How to define the slug for my custom plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, slug

I have created a custom plugin.  How do I define its `slug`?

To clarify, if I attach a custom PHP function to the  [manage_plugins_custom_column hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_plugins_custom_column/), and in that function print the value of the `$plugin_data` array for each plugin in my WordPress installation, that array will contain information about each plugin.  Here is such a function:

```
function opn_render_date( $column_name, $plugin_file, $plugin_data ) {
  error_log( print_r( $plugin_data, true ) );
}
add_action( 'manage_plugins_custom_column', 'opn_render_date', 10, 3 );
```

And [here is example output](https://pastebin.com/uVr9amLY) for one popular plugin in the WordPress repo (Classic Editor).  In that output, the array element `$plugin_data['slug'] => classic-editor` can be seen.  I have created a plugin, installed it, and activated it.  The plugin functions as expected.  But when I print out the same `$plugin_data[]` for my plugin, `$plugin_data['slug']` does not exist. Why is that?  How do I define the `slug` for my plugin?

If the issue is related to the header in my main plugin PHP file, that header can be seen [here](https://pastebin.com/PNUFVqAq).

Maybe a slug is assigned by WordPress, only after a plugin is accepted to the WordPress plugin repo?  I have not yet submitted it there.

edit: To clarify, I've written a plugin that is installed/activated via Dashboard-->Plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually submitted this plugin to the WordPress repo.  As soon as it was accepted, my plugin was assigned a slug.  So it looks like the WordPress plugin admins assign your plugin a slug during the initial review process.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it should be the folder of your plugin.

If you use wp cli, you can use

```
wp plugin list
```

to show all the plugin slugs.

Comment: Here is the name of my plugin's folder (https://i.imgur.com/wkFBeWx.jpg).  If I'm not using wp-cli, how can I show all the plugin slugs?  I may have an issue in which the header in my main plugin file isn't formatted properly.

Comment: Your slug should be 'outdated-plugin-notifier'. You can put `var_dump(get_site_transient('update_plugins'));` on a test page to look at plugin info that would include the [folder]/[filename] of each plugin. Note that it relies on transients, which could be stale (shift-reload page, revisit page later). The name of the folder a plugin resides in is the same as the plugin's slug. To define your slug, name your folder what you want the slug to be.

Comment: Right O.  I understand that my slug *should* be `outdated-plugin-notifiier`.  My issue is that WordPress doesn't seem to recognize that I have a plugin with that slug (or that WordPress doesn't seem to recognize that I have a plugin at all).  I added a function to print `get_site_transient('update_plugins')`, attached it to the `wp_head` hook, and loaded my home page.  This is the output:  https://pastebin.com/UCd5W8q8 . It doesn't contain anything about my new plugin.  Here is a screenshot of my plugin admin screen:  https://i.imgur.com/RbiaMmI.jpg.  Thoughts?

Comment: So using `get_site_transient('update_plugins')`, it seems like WP doesn't recognizes that there is any plugin at all.  In the other test I ran (using the `manage_plugins_custom_column` hook), WP recognized a plugin with the name 'Outdated Plugin Notifier,' but didn't seem to recognize any `slug` at all for it.  To be clear, I'm not saying a blank string was defined as the `slug`.  I'm saying that the `slug` is contained in the array element `$plugin_data['slug']`, and the index `slug` is not defined at all in that particular array.  Not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Comment: Sorry, I have an update.  Per your suggestions, on my home page I carried out a hard refresh, then printed `get_site_transient('update_plugins')` again.
 There is slightly different output (see here:  https://pastebin.com/FsBYnSNV).  The output indicates that my plugin is recognized by the `checked` array, but not by the `no_update` array.  Why might that be?  Should I expect that array to contain info on the `Outdated Plugin Notifier` plugin?

Comment: I don't believe that array is relevant if your plugin is not hosted by wordpress.

Comment: OK thanks. That would indeed explain what I'm experiencing.  But do you have a source on that? If possible, I'd like to confirm before I move on.